# What exactly does a citation alert from Google scholar mean?

Tags: google-scholar

I have a Google Scholar profile and this morning, I got the following email (anonymised):

> Scholar Alert: New articles in my profile
>
> [CITATION] Here is the paper title
>   [My Name] – The Proceedings are here …, 2015

So first I thought that someone has cited the paper mentioned in the email, but when I had a look, there were still zero citations. Then I thought, that maybe this article was added to my list of articles, but then I realised that it was already there before. So what exactly does this email tell me?

Answer (score 3):

There are several types of Scholar Alert, which basically boil down to:

- We found one of your articles
- We found some articles that you should read
- We found somebody citing your articles

When you get one that says "New citations to my articles", that's the one you're looking for.  In that email, the articles listed in it are the ones that cite you, not which articles of yours ones being cited (you have to figure that bit out for yourself).

Comment: The OP had received a "New articles in my profile" email, which indicates that a new article was added to his profile by scholar.  It could be an unrecognized duplicate of something that was already there.

Comment: Perhaps you can add more details in your question... are you *sure* it was there before?  Are you *sure* that a *different* article didn't increase its citation count?